# request data from server in backbone

Tags: c#, backbone.js, pagination

I'm working on a project while learning backbone.js. I have a sql database that contains over 54000 records. I'm using backbone to fetch the data from the server. I have the model and controller written in C#. Since I have 54000 records and growing, I didn't want to send all the data to the client, so I setup a server-side pagination.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)//int? SelectedFax)
        {
            const int pageSize = 10;

            var faxUsers = faxUserRepository.GetUsers();

            var faxes = unitOfWork.FaxRepository.GetAll((page??0)*pageSize, pageSize, null,q => q.OrderBy(d => d.FaxSentDate));

            var resultCount = faxes.Count();

            var faxList // some query

            return Json(faxList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

then I have the backbone collection that fetches the data from the server. Currently, the server is sending 10 records of the first page. Now, I want to setup the pagination in the client side so that when I click next, the backbone requests the next page of data which the server returns the result to backbone collection, but I don't know how to do this. Can someone please help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the Backbone.Paginator plugin (http://addyosmani.com/blog/backbone-paginator-new-pagination-components-for-backbone-js/). It does what you want with the server-side "request pager" configuration (see https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator#paginatorrequestpager).

Comment: Thanks David. Do I need to setup the router for pagination in the server side as well?

Comment: If you want users to be able to bookmark a certain page and return to it later, then yes you will have to configure the routes to provide the send the proper parameters so the correct page gets fetched from the server and displayed.